# Android 4.4 Webview setting style from js not working

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

In WebView I am changing an element's height dynamically from js:

```
function resize(newHeight){
    document.getElementById("#div").style.height = newHeight +'!important';
}
```

This works untill Android 4.4, but at and after 4.4 the style applied from js is ignored and the height remains at default value from css.

Upon many tests I tried:

- specifying 'px', '%', 'vh' or '!important'
- using jquery to set new height value
- changing different styles (i.e. "background-color") for different elements
- checked web Developer's element style to see if it set but overwritten

None working. I read that Android made some changes to webview in 4.4 but could not find a working solution. Is there any way to set style from js in Android 4.4?